# Rotation stuck on X axis only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to script what animation should be played. Here's what I have until now, however, when I move backwards, I don't get "walkBack" but "walk". Why is that?

```
    if (isRunning)
        animator.Play("run");

    if(characterController.velocity.z < 0)
        animator.Play("walkBack");

    if (!isRunning)
        animator.Play("walk");

    if (characterController.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        animator.Play("idle");
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, that when the character rotates, only the character model (with the camera attached to the head, which is attached to the body) does. The CharacterController and the script is on the parent, which only moves, but doesn't rotate. How can I get the direction of the child?

Thank you!!!

Comment: sounds like running is false and is overwriting your choice of walkback

Comment: You were right! Thank you! Should've posted it as an answer so I can mark it!

Comment: tbh it is too obvious an answer :P

Comment: Sorry, it worked with the isRunning and walk, so I thought it would work like that! Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like isrunning is false, therefore overwrites walkBack...

Comment: Whoever disliked it, like it. He was right!

Comment: <cough> she!!!!

Comment: Oups! Sorry! Usernames on the internet are almost always gender-neutral. Am I male or female? :D